# How to merge the dyadic data in R?

Tags: r, merge, merging-data

I am trying to merge two data frames: `DF1` and `DF2`. The `DF1` is my data and the `DF2` is not, but it has some variables that I want to add to my data: variables "flow1" and  "flow2".

The data is dyadic so I create dyadic ID

```
DF1 <- within(DF1, ID <- paste(ccode2,ccode1,year)) # assume this order is right
DF2 <- within(DF2, ID <- paste(ccode1,ccode2, year))
```

Merging:

```
variables <- c("ID", "flow1", "flow2") # flow1 and flow2 are the variables that I want to add to my data. 

DF3<- merge(DF1, DF2[,variables], by=c("ID"), all.x=T) # dec 9
```

The problem is that it doesn't really work, but it should since I have done this many times before.

- What is it that I am doing wrong here?

Reproducible example, DF1

dput(DF1) structure(list(ccode1 = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L,

> 100L,  100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L,
>   100L,  100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L,
>   100L,  100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L,
>   100L,  100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L,
>   100L,  100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L,
>   100L,  100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L,
>   100L,  100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L,
>   100L,  100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L,
>   100L,  100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L,
>   100L,  100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L,
>   100L,  100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L,
>   100L,  100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L,
>   100L,  100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L,
>   100L,  100L), ccode2 = c(101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L,
>   101L,  101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 110L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L,
>   130L,  130L, 130L, 130L, 130L, 130L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 135L,
>   135L,  135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 140L,
>   140L,  140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L,
>   140L,  140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 145L, 145L, 145L, 145L, 145L,
>   145L,  150L, 150L, 150L, 155L, 155L, 155L, 155L, 155L, 155L, 155L,
>   155L,  155L, 155L, 155L, 155L, 155L, 155L, 155L, 160L, 160L, 160L,
>   160L,  160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L,
>   160L,  160L, 165L, 165L, 165L, 165L, 165L, 165L, 165L, 165L, 165L,
>   165L,  165L, 165L, 165L, 165L, 165L, 165L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L,  20L,
>   20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 200L,  200L,
>   200L, 200L), year = c(1991L, 1992L, 1992L, 1994L, 1995L,  1997L,
>   2000L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2008L, 2009L, 1996L, 1995L,  2001L, 2003L,
>   2008L, 2009L, 1997L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2008L,  2009L, 1991L, 1992L,
>   1992L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L,  2000L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L,
>   2005L, 2008L, 2009L, 1991L, 1992L,  1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L,
>   1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 2000L,  2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2008L,
>   2009L, 1991L, 1996L,  1998L, 2000L, 2004L, 2005L, 1998L, 2001L, 2008L,
>   1991L, 1992L,  1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 2000L,
>   2001L,  2002L, 2003L, 2008L, 2009L, 1991L, 1992L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L,
>   1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 2000L, 2001L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L,  2008L,
>   2009L, 1991L, 1992L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L,  1997L, 1998L,
>   2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2008L, 2009L,  1991L, 1992L, 1992L,
>   1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L,  2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L,
>   2004L, 2008L, 2009L, 1991L, 1992L,  1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L,
>   1997L, 1998L, 2000L, 2001L,  2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2008L, 2009L,
>   1991L, 1992L, 1992L,  1993L), ID = c("101 100 1991", "101 100 1992",
>   "101 100 1992",  "101 100 1994", "101 100 1995", "101 100 1997", "101
>   100 2000",  "101 100 2003", "101 100 2004", "101 100 2005", "101 100
>   2008",  "101 100 2009", "110 100 1996", "115 100 1995", "115 100
>   2001",  "115 100 2003", "115 100 2008", "115 100 2009", "130 100
>   1997",  "130 100 2003", "130 100 2004", "130 100 2005", "130 100
>   2008",  "130 100 2009", "135 100 1991", "135 100 1992", "135 100
>   1992",  "135 100 1994", "135 100 1995", "135 100 1996", "135 100
>   1997",  "135 100 1998", "135 100 2000", "135 100 2002", "135 100
>   2003",  "135 100 2004", "135 100 2005", "135 100 2008", "135 100
>   2009",  "140 100 1991", "140 100 1992", "140 100 1992", "140 100
>   1993",  "140 100 1994", "140 100 1995", "140 100 1996", "140 100
>   1996",  "140 100 1997", "140 100 1998", "140 100 2000", "140 100
>   2001",  "140 100 2002", "140 100 2003", "140 100 2004", "140 100
>   2005",  "140 100 2008", "140 100 2009", "145 100 1991", "145 100
>   1996",  "145 100 1998", "145 100 2000", "145 100 2004", "145 100
>   2005",  "150 100 1998", "150 100 2001", "150 100 2008", "155 100
>   1991",  "155 100 1992", "155 100 1992", "155 100 1993", "155 100
>   1994",  "155 100 1995", "155 100 1996", "155 100 1997", "155 100
>   1998",  "155 100 2000", "155 100 2001", "155 100 2002", "155 100
>   2003",  "155 100 2008", "155 100 2009", "160 100 1991", "160 100
>   1992",  "160 100 1992", "160 100 1993", "160 100 1994", "160 100
>   1995",  "160 100 1996", "160 100 1997", "160 100 1998", "160 100
>   2000",  "160 100 2001", "160 100 2003", "160 100 2004", "160 100
>   2005",  "160 100 2008", "160 100 2009", "165 100 1991", "165 100
>   1992",  "165 100 1992", "165 100 1993", "165 100 1994", "165 100
>   1995",  "165 100 1996", "165 100 1997", "165 100 1998", "165 100
>   2000",  "165 100 2001", "165 100 2002", "165 100 2003", "165 100
>   2004",  "165 100 2008", "165 100 2009", "2 100 1991", "2 100 1992", "2
>   100 1992",  "2 100 1993", "2 100 1994", "2 100 1995", "2 100 1996", "2
>   100 1997",  "2 100 1998", "2 100 2000", "2 100 2001", "2 100 2002", "2
>   100 2003",  "2 100 2004", "2 100 2008", "2 100 2009", "20 100 1991",
>   "20 100 1992",  "20 100 1992", "20 100 1993", "20 100 1994", "20 100
>   1995", "20 100 1996",  "20 100 1997", "20 100 1998", "20 100 2000",
>   "20 100 2001", "20 100 2002",  "20 100 2003", "20 100 2004", "20 100
>   2005", "20 100 2008", "20 100 2009",  "200 100 1991", "200 100 1992",
>   "200 100 1992", "200 100 1993" )), row.names = c(NA, 150L), .Names =
>   c("ccode1", "ccode2", "year",  "ID"), class = "data.frame")

Reproducible example, DF2

> dput(DF2) structure(list(ccode1 = structure(c(13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L,
>   13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L,  13L,
>   13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L,  13L, 13L,
>   13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L,  13L, 13L, 13L,
>   13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L,  13L, 13L, 13L, 13L,
>   13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L,  13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L,
>   13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L,  13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L,
>   13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L,  13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L,
>   13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L,  13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L,
>   13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L,  13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L,
>   13L, 13L, 13L, 13L,  13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L,
>   13L, 13L, 13L,  13L, 13L), .Label = c("100", "101", "110", "115",
>   "130", "135",  "140", "145", "150", "155", "160", "165", "2", "20",
>   "200", "205",  "210", "211", "212", "220", "221", "223", "225", "230",
>   "232",  "235", "255", "290", "305", "31", "310", "315", "316", "317", 
>   "325", "331", "338", "339", "341", "343", "344", "345", "346",  "347",
>   "349", "350", "352", "355", "359", "360", "365", "366",  "367", "368",
>   "369", "370", "371", "372", "373", "375", "380",  "385", "390", "395",
>   "40", "402", "403", "404", "41", "411",  "42", "420", "432", "433",
>   "434", "435", "436", "437", "438",  "439", "450", "451", "452", "461",
>   "471", "475", "481", "482",  "483", "484", "490", "500", "501", "51",
>   "510", "516", "517",  "52", "520", "522", "53", "530", "531", "54",
>   "540", "541", "55",  "551", "552", "553", "56", "560", "565", "57",
>   "570", "571",  "572", "58", "580", "581", "590", "591", "60", "600",
>   "615",  "616", "620", "625", "630", "640", "645", "651", "652", "660",
>   "663", "666", "670", "679", "690", "692", "694", "696", "698",  "70",
>   "700", "701", "702", "703", "704", "705", "710", "710.1",  "712",
>   "713", "731", "732", "740", "750", "760", "770", "771",  "775", "780",
>   "781", "790", "80", "800", "811", "812", "816",  "820", "830", "835",
>   "840", "850", "860", "90", "900", "91",  "910", "92", "920", "93",
>   "935", "94", "940", "946", "947", "95",  "950", "955", "970", "983",
>   "986", "987"), class = "factor"), 
>       ccode2 = c(20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
>       20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
>       31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
>       31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
>       40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 41L, 
>       41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
>       41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
>       42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
>       42L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
>       51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 
>       52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 
>       52L, 52L, 52L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 
>       53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L), year = c(1991L, 
>       1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 
>       2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 
>       1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 
>       2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
>       2009L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 
>       1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 
>       2008L, 2009L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 
>       1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 
>       2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 
>       1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 
>       2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 
>       1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 
>       2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 
>       1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 
>       2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 
>       1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 
>       2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L), flow1 = c(93736.1, 101292, 
>       113617, 131956, 148304, 159746, 171440, 178048, 198829, 229191, 
>       220138, 213954, 227652, 259807, 291944, 307823, 317604, 339712, 
>       228376, 488.2, 607.1, 375.2, 219.8, 170.5, 178.3, 179.5, 
>       153.8, 200.3, 278.4, 328.3, 477.8, 500, 667.4, 726.3, 475.4, 
>       523.2, 626.5, 844.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.6, 0.4, 0, 
>       0.2, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.3, 0, 0, 297.1, 110.7, 161.8, 62.2, 
>       137.9, 151.3, 197.1, 281.4, 306.4, 308.6, 272, 263.8, 341.4, 
>       380.7, 458.5, 508.5, 500.2, 464.3, 566, 2095.1, 2452.4, 2757.5, 
>       3187.8, 3511.3, 3677, 4444.7, 4551.1, 4392.7, 4474.4, 4286.4, 
>       4271.1, 4557.8, 4637.8, 4721.4, 4649.2, 4327.9, 4087.2, 3420.7, 
>       618.1, 644.4, 766.4, 789.8, 894.7, 889.8, 779.7, 798.3, 728.4, 
>       669.2, 496.2, 421.3, 523.9, 342.9, 410.9, 561.5, 788.8, 783.8, 
>       501, 920.5, 921.7, 872.8, 1199.1, 1054.4, 1105.5, 1227.2, 
>       1071.4, 1407.3, 2353.3, 2590.3, 2664.3, 4708.9, 6266, 8342.2, 
>       8822.4, 9341.7, 9471.3, 5623.8, 32.3, 31.7, 35.1, 35.7, 52, 
>       42.5, 43.3, 36.6, 59.9, 40.9, 40.9, 35.7, 45.4, 38.2, 33.4, 
>       35.2, 39.9), flow2 = c(82527.6, 87223.5, 96534.8, 109591, 
>       119886, 126088, 145143, 149054, 157847, 169068, 155205, 152969, 
>       159630, 176258, 195151, 211247, 226411, 235479, 180387, 793.1, 
>       783.75, 774.51, 754.05, 726.55, 797.5, 1472.77, 896.5, 929.5, 
>       1157.97, 1124.09, 1072.61, 1192.73, 1300.31, 1945.79, 2516.91, 
>       2720.41, 3036.33, 2700.83, 1.43, 1.43, 2.64, 4.84, 6.38, 
>       6.05, 10.12, 3.85, 5.5, 3.41, 7.48, 158.95, 287.1, 440.44, 
>       397.87, 382.47, 491.7, 789.8, 586.74, 431.31, 238.26, 243.43, 
>       231.55, 605.88, 520.85, 549.78, 602.58, 668.91, 274.94, 247.44, 
>       227.29, 214.17, 312.35, 756.91, 890.23, 781.77, 1038.95, 
>       870.76, 999.47, 1099.42, 1187.37, 1080.48, 885.01, 659.92, 
>       4726.42, 5454.31, 5767.71, 6307.21, 5658.44, 4687.65, 4634.96, 
>       4777.08, 5179.24, 5882.69, 6491.72, 6889.92, 5510.95, 924.33, 
>       1032.13, 1224.08, 1173.04, 1562.88, 1639.88, 1559.14, 1534.49, 
>       1451.32, 1561.22, 1544.3, 1564.79, 1619.1, 1622.87, 1962.2, 
>       2219.1, 2724.42, 3333.12, 1895.58, 656.02, 601.51, 545.79, 
>       564.33, 877.73, 817.83, 1580.89, 1354.41, 1104.23, 807.69, 
>       1323.49, 1242.42, 1170.62, 1327.81, 1583.01, 1776.28, 1957.34, 
>       2476.32, 2188.12, 253.89, 211.38, 219.43, 247.96, 312.83, 
>       360.84, 451.85, 427.54, 454.06, 480.19, 449.38, 440.12, 453.03, 
>       519.8, 595.28, 487.41, 502.26), ID = c("2 20 1991", "2 20 1992", 
>       "2 20 1993", "2 20 1994", "2 20 1995", "2 20 1996", "2 20 1997", 
>       "2 20 1998", "2 20 1999", "2 20 2000", "2 20 2001", "2 20 2002", 
>       "2 20 2003", "2 20 2004", "2 20 2005", "2 20 2006", "2 20 2007", 
>       "2 20 2008", "2 20 2009", "2 31 1991", "2 31 1992", "2 31 1993", 
>       "2 31 1994", "2 31 1995", "2 31 1996", "2 31 1997", "2 31 1998", 
>       "2 31 1999", "2 31 2000", "2 31 2001", "2 31 2002", "2 31 2003", 
>       "2 31 2004", "2 31 2005", "2 31 2006", "2 31 2007", "2 31 2008", 
>       "2 31 2009", "2 40 1991", "2 40 1992", "2 40 1993", "2 40 1994", 
>       "2 40 1995", "2 40 1996", "2 40 1997", "2 40 1998", "2 40 1999", 
>       "2 40 2000", "2 40 2001", "2 40 2002", "2 40 2003", "2 40 2004", 
>       "2 40 2005", "2 40 2006", "2 40 2007", "2 40 2008", "2 40 2009", 
>       "2 41 1991", "2 41 1992", "2 41 1993", "2 41 1994", "2 41 1995", 
>       "2 41 1996", "2 41 1997", "2 41 1998", "2 41 1999", "2 41 2000", 
>       "2 41 2001", "2 41 2002", "2 41 2003", "2 41 2004", "2 41 2005", 
>       "2 41 2006", "2 41 2007", "2 41 2008", "2 41 2009", "2 42 1991", 
>       "2 42 1992", "2 42 1993", "2 42 1994", "2 42 1995", "2 42 1996", 
>       "2 42 1997", "2 42 1998", "2 42 1999", "2 42 2000", "2 42 2001", 
>       "2 42 2002", "2 42 2003", "2 42 2004", "2 42 2005", "2 42 2006", 
>       "2 42 2007", "2 42 2008", "2 42 2009", "2 51 1991", "2 51 1992", 
>       "2 51 1993", "2 51 1994", "2 51 1995", "2 51 1996", "2 51 1997", 
>       "2 51 1998", "2 51 1999", "2 51 2000", "2 51 2001", "2 51 2002", 
>       "2 51 2003", "2 51 2004", "2 51 2005", "2 51 2006", "2 51 2007", 
>       "2 51 2008", "2 51 2009", "2 52 1991", "2 52 1992", "2 52 1993", 
>       "2 52 1994", "2 52 1995", "2 52 1996", "2 52 1997", "2 52 1998", 
>       "2 52 1999", "2 52 2000", "2 52 2001", "2 52 2002", "2 52 2003", 
>       "2 52 2004", "2 52 2005", "2 52 2006", "2 52 2007", "2 52 2008", 
>       "2 52 2009", "2 53 1991", "2 53 1992", "2 53 1993", "2 53 1994", 
>       "2 53 1995", "2 53 1996", "2 53 1997", "2 53 1998", "2 53 1999", 
>       "2 53 2000", "2 53 2001", "2 53 2002", "2 53 2003", "2 53 2004", 
>       "2 53 2005", "2 53 2006", "2 53 2007")), row.names = c(NA,  150L), .Names = c("ccode1", "ccode2", "year", "flow1", "flow2",  "ID"), class
>   = "data.frame")

Comment: That's probably because the columns `ID` you have created don't share the same values. Try `length(setdiff(DF2$ID, DF1$ID)) == length(DF1$ID)` and `length(setdiff(DF2$ID, DF1$ID)) == length(DF2$ID)` to make sure. If either of these checks returns `TRUE`, then your `ID` columns don't share values to join on.

Comment: Thanks @Abdou. Both returns FALSE though.